# Ist "Quereinsteiger" eine abwertende Bezeichnung?

Tags: word-usage, connotation

I war heute bei einem IT-Vortrag, wo der Referent unter anderem meinte, dass man im Marketing-Bereich das Wort "Quereinsteiger" meidet, da es eine abwertende Konnotation habe.

Ich persönlich finde es nicht so. Zwar wird damit einer ohne passenden Abschluss auf seinem Gebiet gemeint, ich habe aber das Wort überwiegend im positiven Kontext gehört ("er hat keinen Abschluss, dennoch hat er viel erreicht).

Wird das Wort auch für negative, abwertende Bezeichnung eines, der keinen (richtigen) Abschluss hat verwendet? Was ist daran abwertend?

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach hat "Quereinsteiger" selbst keinen negativen Beigeschmack. In manchen Bereichen herrscht jedoch ein Elite-Denken, dass besagt dass jeder ohne formale Ausbildung in dem Gebiet (oder dem "falschen" Studium) automatisch schlechter ist. Dort könnte "Quereinsteiger" quasi als Schimpfwort verwendet werden.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Das kann ich auch nachvollziehen. Es gibt auch sogenannte "geschützte Berufe" (wie, z.B., Arzt), wo man ohne Abschluss gar nicht arbeiten darf. Dagegen sind Quereinsteiger in IT-Branche keine Seltenheit, und genau deswegen habe ich mich über die Aussage des Referenten so gewundert.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Man findet für jeden Begriff eine abwertende Bedeutung, vor allem wenn er sarkastisch verwendet wird. Manche Leute machen sich dann zu viele Gedanken.

Ich bin selbst Quereinsteiger in meinem Beruf. Ich bezeichne mich auch selbst als solchen. Das einzige "abwertende" ist, dass man ein geringeres Gehalt bekommt, als Leute die in diesem Beruf ausgebildet wurden. Ich bezweifle allerdings, dass sich das mit einer anderen Bezeichung ändert.

Also, nein, ich kenne keine negative Verwendung des Wortes (außer ironischen/sarkistischen Bemerkungen, die es bei jedem Begriff gibt).

Comment: Vielleicht hängt es ein wenig vom Beruf ab, den man vorher hatte, aber eigentlich kenne ich auch keinen negativen Beigeschmack.

Comment: @Takkat Ich war Kinderarzt, bevor ich nach Deutschland kam ;) Soll das irgendwie abwertend für meine hiesige Tätigkeit als freberuflicher Datenbankentwickler sein?

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin: Keinesfalls. Ich kenne hauptsächlich nur Klagen von Quereinsteigern, die in der selben Branche dann eine höhere Position erlangen und sich nicht so recht ernst genommen fühlen.

Answer (score 13):

In einigen wenigen Berufsfeldern wird das Wort verwendet, um zu signalisieren, daß dem beschriebenen Mitarbeiter wesentliche Qualifikationen fehlen, die er nur auf dem regulären Weg zum Beruf hätte erwerben können.

Mir fällt als gängiges Beispiel dafür vor allem der Beruf des Lehrers ein, bei dem Quereinsteigern regelmäßig (berechtigt oder unberechtigt) auch nach jahrelanger Unterrichtspraxis unterstellt wird zwar über exzellente fachbebzogene Kenntnisse zu verfügen, aber pädagogisch und/oder didaktisch erhebliche Defizite zu haben.

Hier dient das Wort "Quereinsteiger" dann gerne als Vokabel um die Defizite zu beschreiben. Da im allgemeinen Sprachverständnis das Wort eher positiv besetzt ist (und mit Flexibilität und Engagement assoziiert wird), ist das ausgesprochen diffizil, da zum Verständnis der Konnotation das Wissen um den Hintergrund des Sprechers, sowie der Empfängergruppe notwendig ist.

Comment: +1 für die Konnotation bei Lehrern. Bei anderen Berufen hätte ich persönlich keine spezielle negative Bedeutung.

Answer (score 10):

In manchen Fällen kann es sogar positiv ausgelegt werden. Wie z. B. ein politischer Quereinsteiger, um zu signalisieren, dass man kein reiner Parteipolitiker ist.